# Create Outllook appointments from ASP.NET MVC applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, outlook, exchange-server, icalendar

I'm working on ASP.MVC 3 web site and need to automatically create Outlook appointemnts, events, reminders etc from it. I've googled a bit and read some posts here and find the following options:

1) Create iCal files and ask users to execute them. Not acceptable for me because appointments can be created via Web Interface from any device (e.g. Android, iPhone etc) with no Outlook installed.

2) I'm not sure it can be realized, but if my users will login to my site via their domain password (SSO) will I be able to create appointment for logged in user via Outlook App installed on the server or via exchange server somehow?

3) Alternatively can I use some predefined exchange user that will create tasks, appointments and events in outlook for logged in used?

4) Any other options can be here?

Comment: I wouldn't be so quick to dismiss #1. iPhone / Android / Blackberry are quite happy to handle those files with their native apps. All the user would need is to be able to setup syncing of their exchange calendar with their phone. It's a fairly universal means of communicating appointments.

Comment: Android won't without an extra app.

Comment: ok, but this solution is not quite handy for users who has to perform additional actions to execute iCal file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On account of the fact that this works: http://w3mentor.com/learn/asp-dot-net-c-sharp/c-interoperability/sending-mail-using-outlook-in-c-asp-net/ and this works: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa168022(v=office.11).aspx then I would say that option 2 is definitely doable.

iOS 3 and above lets iCal files work, they don't on Android though, as you say.

Comment: Thanks for the links. One more option appeared in my head is to run outlook on client machine via active X and add items via active X. Similar behavior as Sharepoint has. But I doubt it works on other browsers rather than IE. But this, of course, will require using the system from machine with Outlook installed.